# background transitioning / changing with fade

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net, html

Heu Guys.

What are the common ways to achieve a background change (slide show basically), with a transition effect. I want to change the comeplte document background at time intervals.

I am a ASP.net developer, and would like to most of it natively in ASP. I have been know to include Java an jquery when REALLY needed. HTML 5 maybe?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has fadeIn/fadeOut/slideUp/slideDown